# Creating an alternative way to scroll TableView on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I currently have a TableView with over 35,000 cells.  Obviously the standard iPhone flick-and-scroll becomes inefficient with this many cells.  I have already implemented search but still think that a way to scroll the entire table is necessary.  I am currently using the

```
-sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:
```

method to populate the side with the relevant characters, and I want similar functionality to that in Apple's Remote app.  I do not have section titles in my table and simply want the sectionIndex to be an alternative way to scroll through the entire 35,000 cell table.  How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

My instinct tells me that a list that large could probably be broken down into smaller sections that could be filtered using the standard hierarchical navigation on the iPhone - that said, without knowing what exactly the data is I can't say that with any confidence.

You say you don't have any section titles - is the list alphanumeric? If so, what is wrong with having a standard alphabetical sectionIndex and sectionTitles?

Comment: The data is the alphabet from another language. THe problem is that the database I am using doesn't have section titles, and if I haven't been misinformed you must use NSDictionary to use section titles.  A workaround for this I thought would simply be to use the sectionIndex view to scroll regularly like the Remote App from Apple

Comment: Or if you could point me to a good tutorial for adding section index titles in manually, that would help. (Hard-Coded?)

Comment: I'd avoid using the section index as some kind of custom scroller as thats not what its intended for.

I'm curious, which alphabet has 350k members?

Comment: i have a 35,000 word dictionary and the alphabet only has 35 characters.  THe section index displays the alphabet and is supposed to somehow scroll.  I was thinking maybe there could be a UISlider with alpha 0 overlayed the sectionIndex and somehow be used to scroll the entire table, but it seems a bit complicated.  I'm curios to know how Apple and various other apps that have custom scrolling did it.

Comment: If you already have a section index setup, then you shouldn't need to do anything else - it already implements the fast scrolling behavior.